# How to use purrr::map to base::assign?

Tags: r, purrr

How to get from meow to purr?

Let's say I have a list with 2 elements "a" and "b". I want to copy these elements into my Global environment. If I wanted to just add these elements to the search path, I'd use assign. However, I want to create a copy. And I'd like to use purrr::map to do this. How does it work?

```
mylist <- list(a=1:2, b=3:4)

#nope
map(mylist, assign, x=names(.), value=.)

#no
map(mylist, assign(x=names(.), value=.))

#no
map2(mylist, names(mylist), assign(x=.y, value=.x) )

#no
map2(mylist, names(mylist), assign, x=.y, value=.x )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several responses to this :-)

1. **Don't.** My first visceral and emphatic response: don't do that. Very rarely do I find the use of `get`/`assign` justified, most commonly they are indications of inefficient (if not poor) data management. Having similar-structured things in a `list` means that you can efficiently operate on them (using `map` or `lapply` or similar).
2. Base R does this very efficiently with `list2env`.

   ```r
   ls()
   # character(0)
   list2env(list(a=1:2, b=3:4), envir = .GlobalEnv)
   # <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
   ls()
   # [1] "a" "b"
   ```
3. If you must use `purrr`, then what you need is both the name and the value, so use `purrr::imap`:

   ```r
   ls()
   # character(0)
   imap(list(a=1:2, b=3:4), ~ assign(..2, ..1, envir = .GlobalEnv))
   # $a
   # [1] 1 2
   # $b
   # [1] 3 4
   ls()
   # [1] "a" "b"
   ```

   The reason your `assign` calls failed was that it was assigning it to the then-current environment, which is neither global nor something you get to use after your call to `map`/`map2`.

Comment: Thanks, `imap` is what I was looking for. I think I missed its introduction. The use of `..1` and `..2` wasn't clear to me, but this makes sense.

Comment: You can mimic `imap` with `map2(lst, names(lst), ...)`. What you were missing is `envir=`.

Answer (score 2):

Easier is `list2env` from `base R` applied directly on the named `list`  to create the objects from the `names` in the global environment

```
list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Regarding the use of `map`, it returns only the value and not the `names`

---

A slightly related to this topic would be destructuring assignment.  In `R`, this can be done with `%<-%` operator from `zeallot`

```
library(zeallot)
c(a, b) %<-% mylist
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to `zeallot` . This can be useful.